# ANTLR4 CSharp Lexer produces error with unicode source code files

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am using the CSharp Java target - i am parsing some Csharp code like this:

```
List<Token> codeTokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
List<Token> commentTokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
//CharStream cs = CharStreams.fromString(contents);
CharStream cs = CharStreams.fromPath(path);
CSharpLexer lexer = new CSharpLexer(cs);
// recognition error happens here: 
List<? extends Token> tokens = lexer.getAllTokens();
List<Token> directiveTokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
ListTokenSource directiveTokenSource = new ListTokenSource(directiveTokens);
CommonTokenStream directiveTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(directiveTokenSource, CSharpLexer.DIRECTIVE);
CSharpPreprocessorParser preprocessorParser = new CSharpPreprocessorParser(directiveTokenStream);
```

If my source code is ASCII encoded, it works fine. But if it's UNICODE, even if there's nothing in the file, I always get this error:

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '﻿'
```

Do I need to configure my Lexer differently? The error comes from Lexer.java => getAllTokens() => nextToken() => getInterpreter().match(_input, _mode);

Again, I get this even with an empty UNICODE-encoded file - but it still contains the U+FEFF character:

```
$ less ApiUserInfo.cs
<U+FEFF>
ApiUserInfo.cs (END)
```

Thank you
Angel

Comment: You will need to use an editor that does not include the Byte Order Marker at the start.
Do you know which Unicode serialisation you are using - I would recommend using UTF-8, which should not carry a BOM (although Windows' Notepad does add one)

Comment: I fixed it by adding this rule to the CSharp Lexer: BYTE_ORDER_MARK: '\u00EF\u00BB\u00BF';
BOM     : '\uFEFF'{ skip(); };

Comment: In fact FEFF is the UTF-16 one : ) the previous one (first line) is the UTF-8 one . Thank you